# Consensus/ranked ordering algorithm

Tags: algorithms, sorting, consensus

Say I have a set of numbers, for example `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. Is there an algorithm that allows these numbers to be put into a consensus ordering based on a ranked vote? For example, if 3 people vote and their votes are `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, `[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]`, and `[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]`, then the consensus ordering would be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Ideally the algorithm would support votes of partial orderings as well, such as `[2, 5, 4]`.

I'm pretty sure I can extend the [ranked voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_voting) system to produce a complete ordering of the "candidates," but I'm wondering if there's already an algorithm to do this.

Comment: This is a popular topic in social choice theory, known as vote aggregation. See for example [this link](http://lorrie.cranor.org/pubs/diss/node4.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have both good news, and bad news.  Not only is there a way to do it; there are many candidate ways to do it.  For instance, you could use IRV, Condorcet voting, Borda count, or many other schemes.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_voting and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_choice_theory.

Unfortunately, there are also negative results showing that no scheme provides all of the properties that we might desire.   See Arrow's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_paradox.

Comment: As far as I can tell, all these techniques provide a single winner (condorcet) or an ordering of only the top n candidates. Techniques for the latter don't seem too amenable to the case where n is the total number of candidates. Regardless, iteratively applying a condorcet method or simply picking the most popular candidate at each iteration seems sufficient for my application. Thanks!